# jQuery JSON Issue

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I compiled my data into JSON via php with 2 parameters `response` and `status`. Response has the data which PHP gets when AJAX is processed and status is the error code or success command.

Now, when I pass the data to jQuery, it comes up with weird back and forward slashes, although are don't appear if I `console.log(data.response)` on AJAX. Please help ..

**IMAGE OF OUTPUT**

[image: OUTPUT]

**THE JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.tax-filter').click( function(event) {

        // Prevent defualt action - opening tag page
        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }

        // Get tag slug from title attirbute
        var selecetd_taxonomy = $(this).attr('title');

        $('.tagged-posts').fadeOut();

        data = {
            action: 'filter_posts',
            afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce,
            taxonomy: selecetd_taxonomy,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
            data: data,
            success: function( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {

                $('.tagged-posts').html( data.response );
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
                /*console.log( data );
                console.log( XMLHttpRequest );*/
            },
            error: function( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                /*console.log( MLHttpRequest );
                console.log( textStatus );
                console.log( errorThrown );*/
                $('.tagged-posts').html( 'No posts found' );
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
            }
        })

    });
});
```

**THE PHP (WP)**

```
// Script for getting posts
function ajax_filter_get_posts( $taxonomy ) {

  // Verify nonce
  if( !isset( $_POST['afp_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce' ) )
    die('Permission denied');

  $taxonomy = $_POST['taxonomy'];

    wp_reset_postdata();
    // WP Query
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'std9_photographs',
      'posts_per_page'  => -1,
      'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                'taxonomy' => 'std9_photograph_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $taxonomy,
              ),
            ),
      );

    // If taxonomy is not set, remove key from array and get all posts
    if( !$taxonomy ) {
      unset( $args['tag'] );
    }

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $result = '';
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

      $result['response'][] = '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'. get_the_title().' </a></h2>';
      $result['status']     = 'success';

    endwhile; else:
      $result['response'] = '<h2>No posts found</h2>';
      $result['status']   = '404';
    endif;

    $result = json_encode($result);
    echo $result;

    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON will add slashes when needed (so don't worry about that). The problem is that jQuery has problem to parse that data. You are probably facing a problem encoding your response.

**Edit:** In order to avoid your backslashes try encoding with the following command  `json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

The reason that you are having this forward and back slashes is because you are adding in your response html code with `</h2> </a>` etc.

Comment: So, how do I close these html statements?

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. The backslashes are gone now, but formatting is not correct. The thing is, it comes up fine in some cases. In other, it add's these weird statements .. (http://take.ms/wwmS1)

Comment: You can use the code I posted after my edit if you need to keep that html code in your response. Otherwise you can return the data and replace your html in the "success" by adding extra elements in your code, like the following $('.posts').html('<h2>'+resp.data+'</h2>');

Comment: @ZainSohail So I guess its fine when you remove the anchor and h2 ?
What happens if you use JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your header is: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Secondly, do a `JSON.parse()` in your javascript to parse response into json object.